# Change route frontend to frontend when login backend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, axios

[vue-laravel]How can i change my frontend route to another frontend route when i login in my backend?
Im new at programming.

```
   async EnvioLogin() {
      const response = await axios.post("api/auth/login", {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
      })
      .catch(error => {
        showError=true,
        setTimeout(sumirErro(),3000);
         });
      localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
    },
```

Comment: Refer https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link

Comment: by the way, if you use async/await use try/catch ... not .catch